# time range between 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, multiset

I have following script

```sql
with  first_step as
(
SELECT  
1 as MY_TYPE,
    2373 as my_id
    ,to_date('15.02.23 17:00'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI') AS  time_from
    ,to_date('17.02.23 12:00' , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')AS  time_till
    from dual
    union all
SELECT  
1 as MY_TYPE,
    2373 as my_id
    ,to_date('16.02.23 14:00'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI') AS  time_from
    ,to_date('16.02.23 15:00' , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')AS  time_till
    from dual
    union all
SELECT  
0 as MY_TYPE,
    2373 as my_id
    ,to_date('14.02.23 22:00'  , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI') AS  time_from
    ,to_date('16.02.23 18:00' , 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')AS  time_till
    from dual
),
second_step as 
(
select 
MY_TYPE,
my_id,
to_date(to_char(time_from +(column_value-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy') AS  my_date,
case when trunc(time_from)  < to_date(to_char(time_from +(column_value-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy') then '00:00' else to_char(time_from,'HH24:MI') end time_from,
case when trunc(time_till) > to_date(to_char(time_from +(column_value-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy') then '23:59' else replace(to_char(time_till,'HH24:MI'),'00:00','23:59') end time_till
from first_step 
   CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
                SELECT
                   level
                from
                    dual
                CONNECT BY time_from  + level-1    <=    time_till
            ) AS sys.odcinumberlist) ) n
)
select * from second_step 
order by 
my_date,time_from, time_till
```

that is what I get

[image: actual result]

But I need that

[image: required result]

So, we have entries which are on the same day, but also entries lasting multiple days. The single day entries should stay as they are, but the multiple days should be stretched.Currently my multiple days entries are not represented correctly. What is wrong with my script?

Comment: Can you share your tables definitions and some inputs ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query:

```sql
with first_step (my_type, my_id, time_from, time_till) as (
  SELECT 1,
         2373,
         to_date('15.02.2023 17:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('17.02.2023 12:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
union all
  SELECT 1,
         2373,
         to_date('16.02.2023 14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('16.02.2023 15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
union all
  SELECT 0,
         2373,
         to_date('14.02.2023 22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('16.02.2023 18:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
),
days (my_type, my_id, time_from, day_end, time_till) AS (
  SELECT my_type,
         my_id,
         time_from,
         TRUNC(time_from) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND,
         time_till
  FROM   first_step
UNION ALL
  SELECT my_type,
         my_id,
         day_end + INTERVAL '1' SECOND,
         day_end + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         time_till
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day_end < time_till
)
SELECT my_type,
       my_id,
       time_from,
       LEAST(day_end, time_till) AS time_till
FROM   days
ORDER BY my_id, time_from, time_till;
```

Or a hierarchical query:

```sql
with first_step (my_type, my_id, time_from, time_till) as (
  SELECT 1,
         2373,
         to_date('15.02.2023 17:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('17.02.2023 12:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
union all
  SELECT 1,
         2373,
         to_date('16.02.2023 14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('16.02.2023 15:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
union all
  SELECT 0,
         2373,
         to_date('14.02.2023 22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI'),
         to_date('16.02.2023 18:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')
  from   dual
)
SELECT my_type,
       my_id,
       GREATEST(time_from, day_start) AS time_from,
       LEAST(time_till, day_end) AS time_till
FROM   first_step f
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT TRUNC(f.time_from) + LEVEL - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS day_start,
                TRUNC(f.time_from) + LEVEL - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS day_end
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY TRUNC(f.time_from) + LEVEL - 1 < f.time_till
       )
ORDER BY my_id, time_from, time_till
```

Which both output:

| MY_TYPE | MY_ID | TIME_FROM | TIME_TILL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2373 | 2023-02-14 22:00:00 | 2023-02-14 23:59:59 |
| 0 | 2373 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00 | 2023-02-15 23:59:59 |
| 1 | 2373 | 2023-02-15 17:00:00 | 2023-02-15 23:59:59 |
| 0 | 2373 | 2023-02-16 00:00:00 | 2023-02-16 18:00:00 |
| 1 | 2373 | 2023-02-16 00:00:00 | 2023-02-16 23:59:59 |
| 1 | 2373 | 2023-02-16 14:00:00 | 2023-02-16 15:00:00 |
| 1 | 2373 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00 | 2023-02-17 12:00:00 |

*Note: `to_date('16.02.23 14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI')` will give you the year `0023` and not `2023`. If you want 2023 then use a 4-digit year or the format model `RR` or `YY`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mMNZoJq2)

Comment: thanks, but can we have only one column with day format which represents every day of the range and another columns for from and till in hour/min format?

Comment: Bingo! You showed me the answer anyway. I need just to change my previous script from "                CONNECT BY time_from  + level-1    <=    time_till" to                 CONNECT BY trunc(time_from)  + level-1    <=    trunc(time_till)

Comment: @kirilb If you want day and time separately then use the queries above and format them with `TO_CHAR` using `DD-MM-YYYY` for the days and `HH24:MI` for the time components. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vJl62SH2)